# How safe is to set relationships to delete on cascade?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship, relationships

I have this big database on mysql (104 tables), where almost every single table has a FK pointing to a single table, like the master table.

There a huge web of relationships, and when I need to delete a record from the 'master' table, obviosly, there a lot of errors because of the relationships. All of them are set to 'Do nothing' on delete, so my question is, really, how safe is to change them (the relatioships) to delete on cascade instead of delete 'by hand' every single record on all of the tables affected?

I'm usyng MySql, last version (don't remmember exactly which one), and, if it works, PHP 5.2 and codeigniter.

Thanks a lot

Comment: safe, to the customer point of view. A minor mistake can lead to a huge lost of data. But, the customer/client of this proyect, shouldn't be touching the database anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about businessrules.

If it is in your businessrules that a cascade delete should happen, I don't see why you program it by hand?

Of course, when programming by hand you can built in extra validations, but If you are not, deleting by hand only make thins more error-prone.

For one thing, when deleting 'by built in cascade' , the transaction is for free, you don't risk to leave orphans.

Comment: some of the guys that are working with me points me that is not that safe in the case, for example, the client touching the database. But I told them that, client shouldn't be doint it anyway

Comment: The huge dataloss also happens when you program it, no?  Asking confirmation is possible either way.